# React Native goBack() with TabNavigator and StackNavigator react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

Probably I am not doing well with react navigation and do not understand how nested navigation works.
I've got `BottomTabNavigator` with `StackNavigator`'s in every component like in the example below.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function AStack(props){
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen name="FirstScreenA" component={FirstScreenA}/>
      <Stack.Screen
                name="SecondScreenA"
                component={SecondScreenA}
                options={{
                    headerLeft:  () => (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} >
                        </TouchableOpacity>/>
    </Stack.Navigator>



<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="A" component={AStack} />
  <Tab.Screen name="B" component={BStack} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Inside `FirstScreenA` component I have button which navigates to `SecondScreenA`.
And by `props.navigaton.goBack()` in `Stack.Screen` I want to go back to the `FirstScreenA`.

In fact, `goBack()` takes me to the previous screen in terms of `Tab.Navigator`. So, if I was in the `BStack` before, `goBack()` in the `AStack` moves me to screen in `BStack`.

My goal is to go back to the previous screen in `AStack`.

As far as I understand `navigation` prop from `Tab.Navigator` automatically goes to Stack Components. In this case I am not able to use anything like `pop(), push(), popToTop()` methods which should help, because those methods are not available in `Tab.Navigator`'s `navigation`. Any hooks with `StackActions` does not work neither.   `navigation.navigate('FristScreenA')` does not work, seems like it is think, that we already in the needed stack and screen, so nothing happens.

I guess there is a way to use internal navigation in Stack (not nested from Tab), but didn't find way to do that. If someone could clarify me and explain what to do - it would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you slove this issue?

Comment: Yep, the chose answer helped me a lot. It needed to re-structure your Navigator Components and it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are receiving `props.navigation` in the stack navigator component `AStack`, which is the direct children of your `TabNavigator`. In react navigation, children receive the `props.navigation` object of their containing parents, in your case, you're reciveing `props.navigation` object of the `TabNavigator`, that's why using `goBack` takes you to the previous Tab of your `TabNavigator`.

To receive navigation props of your stack navigator, you need to do that in your `Stack.Screen` components, in your case in `FirstScreenA` or `SecondScreenA` because they're the direct children of your `StackNavigator`. So using `props.navigation.goBack` in `SecondScreenA` component would actually take you back to `FirstScreenA`.

Comment: @VyachAp You're welcome. Please accept the answer if that solved your issue.